# Why can't ranges be used if in a function?

Tags: c++, c++20, std-ranges

I'm trying to get a `range` like python like below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ranges>

auto Range(double start, double end, double step)
{
    if (start <= end) {
        auto step_fun = [=](auto x) { return x * step + start; };
        auto end_pred = [=](auto x) { return x <= end; };
        auto range =
            std::views::iota(0)
            | std::views::transform(step_fun)
            | std::views::take_while(end_pred);
        return range;
    }
    else {
        auto step_fun = [=](auto x) { return -x * step + start; };
        auto end_pred = [=](auto x) { return x >= end; };
        auto range =
            std::views::iota(0)
            | std::views::transform(step_fun)
            | std::views::take_while(end_pred);
        return range;
    }
}
int main() {
    auto range = Range(108, 100, 1);

    for (auto i : range)
        std::cout << i << ' ';
    return 0;
}
```

But the Visual Studio told me:

```
Error   C3487   'std::ranges::take_while_view<std::ranges::transform_view<std::ranges::iota_view<_Ty,std::unreachable_sentinel_t>,Range::<lambda_3>>,Range::<lambda_4>>': all return expressions must deduce to the same type: previously it was 'std::ranges::take_while_view<std::ranges::transform_view<std::ranges::iota_view<_Ty,std::unreachable_sentinel_t>,Range::<lambda_1>>,Range::<lambda_2>>'
```

and

```
Message     No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called    test
```

But only `start>end`or`start<end`,it can work,like:

```
auto Range(double start, double end, double step)
{
auto step_fun = [=](auto x) { return x * step + start; };
        auto end_pred = [=](auto x) { return x <= end; };
        auto range =
            std::views::iota(0)
            | std::views::transform(step_fun)
            | std::views::take_while(end_pred);
        return range;
}
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: because the predicate is part of signature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A function must have one return type, auto doesn't change that. Your two returns have different, incompatible types, because each lambda expression has a unique type.

The error message rather buried it: `blah blah Range::<lambda_3>,Range::<lambda_4>` vs `blah blah Range::<lambda_1>,Range::<lambda_2>`

You can do some arithmetic to reduce it to one `return`

```
auto Range(double start, double end, double step)
{
    if (start > end) {
        step *= -1;
    }
    int count = (end - start) / step;

    auto step_fun = [=](auto x) { return x * step + start; };
    return std::views::iota(0, count)
         | std::views::transform(step_fun);
}
```

Caveat: this function is still problematic if `step` is negative, you might instead want to throw if `end` is not reachable from `start`.

Comment: Oh, I get it, thank you. I'm silly to forget it.

Comment: @newlearner don't worry, the error message rather buried it: `blah blah Range::<lambda_3>,Range::<lambda_4>` vs `blah blah Range::<lambda_1>,Range::<lambda_2>`

Comment: I need to be more careful. Thank you.

Comment: `if((start>end)==(step>0)) step=-step;` just xnor (bool==bool) to conditions to get what you want! but after that: `if(step==0) count=0; else count=...;`

Answer (score 1):

Because the result type of `take_while` and `transform` contains the function type as part of signature, but one function can only have single return type.

in addition to what already answered, you can also erase the type.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ranges>
#include <functional>

auto Range(double start, double end, double step)
{
    std::function<double(double)> step_fun;
    std::function<double(double)> end_pred;

    if (start <= end) {
        step_fun = [=](auto x) { return x * step + start; };
        end_pred = [=](auto x) { return x <= end; };
    }
    else {
        step_fun = [=](auto x) { return -x * step + start; };
        end_pred = [=](auto x) { return x >= end; };    
    }
    auto range =
            std::views::iota(0)
            | std::views::transform(step_fun)
            | std::views::take_while(end_pred);
    return range;
}
int main() {
    auto range = Range(108, 100, 1);

    for (auto i : range)
        std::cout << i << ' ';
    return 0;
}
```